# How to change the colour of the label of the checked radio button with only css

Tags: html, css

I want to change the colour of the label when that specific radio button is checked, but I am unable to do it, this is my code

**html**

```
<input class="civil-sub-law-type" type="radio" name="civil-sublaw" id="arb" value="arbitration">
<input class="civil-sub-law-type" type="radio" name="civil-sublaw" id="landacq" value="land acquisation">
<input class="civil-sub-law-type" type="radio" name="civil-sublaw" id="comcourt" value="comercial court">
<input class="civil-sub-law-type" type="radio" name="civil-sublaw" id="others" value="others">
<!-- SUB LAW TYPE -->
<article class="civil-sub-law-type-nav">
    <ul class="civil-sub-law-type-ul">
        <li class="civil-sub-law-type-list">
            <label for="arb" class="civil-sub-law-type-label">Arbitration Cases</label>
        </li>
        <li class="civil-sub-law-type-list">
            <label for="landacq" class="civil-sub-law-type-label">Land Acquisation Cases</label>
        </li>
        <li class="civil-sub-law-type-list">
            <label for="comcourt" class="civil-sub-law-type-label">Comercial Court Cases</label>
        </li>
        <li class="civil-sub-law-type-list">
            <label for="others" class="civil-sub-law-type-label">Others</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

**css**

```
.civil-sub-law-type:checked ~ .civil-sub-law-type-label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Please suggest me what should I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to account for each input-label pair specifically, typically by the assigned id.

Second, you have to use `~ *`  rather than just `~`, since the labels are not sibling elements of the checkboxes, but descendants of such siblings.

```css
#arb:checked ~ * label[for="arb"] {
  background-color: red;
}

#landacq:checked ~ * label[for="landacq"] {
  background-color: red;
}

#comcourt:checked ~ * label[for="comcourt"] {
  background-color: red;
}

#others:checked ~ * label[for="others"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input class="civil-sub-law-type" type="radio" name="civil-sublaw" id="arb" value="arbitration">
<input class="civil-sub-law-type" type="radio" name="civil-sublaw" id="landacq" value="land acquisation">
<input class="civil-sub-law-type" type="radio" name="civil-sublaw" id="comcourt" value="comercial court">
<input class="civil-sub-law-type" type="radio" name="civil-sublaw" id="others" value="others">
<!-- SUB LAW TYPE -->
<article class="civil-sub-law-type-nav">
    <ul class="civil-sub-law-type-ul">
        <li class="civil-sub-law-type-list">
            <label for="arb" class="civil-sub-law-type-label">Arbitration Cases</label>
        </li>
        <li class="civil-sub-law-type-list">
            <label for="landacq" class="civil-sub-law-type-label">Land Acquisation Cases</label>
        </li>
        <li class="civil-sub-law-type-list">
            <label for="comcourt" class="civil-sub-law-type-label">Comercial Court Cases</label>
        </li>
        <li class="civil-sub-law-type-list">
            <label for="others" class="civil-sub-law-type-label">Others</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

A bit different and more scalable method, counting the elements rather than using the ids. Also grouped the selectors together since they all use the same color.

```css
.civil-sub-law-type:nth-child(1):checked ~ 
    * .civil-sub-law-type-list:nth-child(1) > label,
.civil-sub-law-type:nth-child(2):checked ~ 
    * .civil-sub-law-type-list:nth-child(2) > label,
.civil-sub-law-type:nth-child(3):checked ~ 
    * .civil-sub-law-type-list:nth-child(3) > label,
.civil-sub-law-type:nth-child(4):checked ~ 
    * .civil-sub-law-type-list:nth-child(4) > label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input class="civil-sub-law-type" type="radio" name="civil-sublaw" id="arb" value="arbitration">
<input class="civil-sub-law-type" type="radio" name="civil-sublaw" id="landacq" value="land acquisation">
<input class="civil-sub-law-type" type="radio" name="civil-sublaw" id="comcourt" value="comercial court">
<input class="civil-sub-law-type" type="radio" name="civil-sublaw" id="others" value="others">
<!-- SUB LAW TYPE -->
<article class="civil-sub-law-type-nav">
    <ul class="civil-sub-law-type-ul">
        <li class="civil-sub-law-type-list">
            <label for="arb" class="civil-sub-law-type-label">Arbitration Cases</label>
        </li>
        <li class="civil-sub-law-type-list">
            <label for="landacq" class="civil-sub-law-type-label">Land Acquisation Cases</label>
        </li>
        <li class="civil-sub-law-type-list">
            <label for="comcourt" class="civil-sub-law-type-label">Comercial Court Cases</label>
        </li>
        <li class="civil-sub-law-type-list">
            <label for="others" class="civil-sub-law-type-label">Others</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

Comment: This is working, but I have many radio buttons so writing the ids of everyone of them will be lengthy. Is there a common waay to do it with class?

Comment: Do you have many radio buttons all on the same group, or the entire setup appears multiple times? If the latter, it may be possible to refer the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.

Comment: I have multiple radio buttons in the same group almost 26 of them so writing each one of them will be difficult

Comment: Then my only suggestion is to use short ids like `a`, `b`, `c` (fits perfectly for 26 buttons! :D ). Or it is possible to switch the whole thing to use JavaScript, which is able to count elements.

Comment: Hey, just realized it can be done in a more scalable way, see my addition to the answer. It wouldn't save you typing for a single input group, but it's more scalable for adding multiple groups as it refers to positions rather than the ids.

Answer (score 1):

Your label and the input should be adjacent

```css
.radio:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input class="radio" name="test" type="radio" />
    <label>
      Test Label
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="radio" name="test" type="radio" />
    <label>
      Test Label 2
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the link is not opening

Comment: This is not working for me

Comment: As per my knowledge, You should change your HTML structure putting the label and the radio button next to each other or the radio inside the lable in order to use a common class and change the label on :checked status of a radio button. Like in the example.

Comment: I tried with the same class that did not work too.

Comment: You can use any class but input and radio should be like in the example. they should be next to each other. then only + combinator can work.

Comment: Not working still